# Initializer for a simple class in Swift erroring out

Tags: swift, oop, swift3

I'm trying to create a class to learn Unit Testing. However, I'm facing some issues which I am struggling with.

My Class:

```
import Foundation

class Monster{

var name: String{
    didSet(newName){
        self.name = validateName(newName: self.name)
    }
}

var level: Int{
    didSet(level){
        if self.level < 0 {
            self.level = 0
        }else if self.level > 100 {
            self.level = 100
        }
    }
}

var hitpoints: Int{
    didSet(newHP){
        print(self.hitpoints)
        if self.hitpoints < 0 {
            self.hitpoints = 0
        }else if self.hitpoints > self.level * 20{
            self.hitpoints = self.level * 20
        }
    }
}

init(name: String, argLevel: Int, argHP: Int) {
    self.name = name;
    self.level = argLevel
//      self.hitpoints = validateHP(newHP: argHP, curLevel: argLevel)
    let newHP = validateHP(newHP: argHP, curLevel: argLevel)
    self.hitpoints = newHP
    self.name = validateName(newName: name)
}

private func validateName(newName: String) -> String{
    return newName.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: "")
}

private func validateHP(newHP: Int, curLevel: Int) -> Int{
    if newHP < 0 {
        return 0
    }else if newHP > 20 * curLevel {
        return 20 * curLevel
    }else{
        return newHP
    }
}

}
```

I'm not able to use this class as I'm getting an error for using validateHP() function in the initializer.

The error: Desktop/UnitTest/UnitTesting/Monster.swift:44:15: Use of 'self' in method call 'validateHP' before all stored properties are initialized

I do not understand this message as I'm not using any stored properties in the function definition or as one of the arguments. Infact, I changed up the entire argument structure so that this would not happen.

If anyone can educate me on what I'm missing here, that would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call an instance method before your instance is initialized.  Try making your `validateHP` and `validateName` `static` functions:

```
init(name: String, argLevel: Int, argHP: Int) {
    self.name = name;
    self.level = argLevel
    //      self.hitpoints = validateHP(newHP: argHP, curLevel: argLevel)
    let newHP = Monster.validateHP(newHP: argHP, curLevel: argLevel)
    self.hitpoints = newHP
    self.name = Monster.validateName(newName: name)
}

private static func validateName(newName: String) -> String {
    return newName.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: "")
}

private static func validateHP(newHP: Int, curLevel: Int) -> Int {
    if newHP < 0 {
        return 0
    } else if newHP > 20 * curLevel {
        return 20 * curLevel
    } else {
        return newHP
    }
}
```

Note: Swift likes spaces around tokens.  I suggest using a space before and after `{` and `}` to separate them from other elements.

Comment: The same needs to be done with the `validateName` function.

Comment: the validate name works fine without static for some reason seems weird. Anyway, I updated it with your code and it is working. Thanks.

Comment: `return newHP < 0 ? 0 : newHP > 20 * curLevel ? 20 * curLevel : newHP`